# Not able to change background-color based on decision value inside JSON data

Tags: jquery, html, css, json

I'm trying to change the `background-color` of an element based on a local variable. The variable looks like the following in JSON:

`{"decision": "0"}`

**The HTML:**

```
<div ><p id="status-message">&quot;Status Message&quot;<p></p></div>
        <br>
      <span id="auth">AUTH</span>
    <span id="decline">DECLINE</span>
```

**Their respective CSS inside of `<head>`:**

```
#status-message {
color:red;
background:white;
display:none;
}
#auth {
    border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    background-color:#efefef;
    color:black;
    width: 50px;
    border-color:maroon;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: large;
}
#decline {
    border: px solid #a1a1a1;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    background-color:#efefef;
    color:black;
    width: 90px;
    border-color:maroon;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-width: 1px;;
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: large;
}
```

**And finally the JQuery:** (please note that I have tested the `decision` variable in the `if` statement with both double and single quotations as well as without quotations)

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: url,
       dataType: 'text',
       success: function(data) {
       var jsonobj = $.parseJSON(data)
var decision =  jsonobj['decision']
       if (decision == "0"){
           $("auth").css("background-color", 'green');
           $("status-message").css("display", 'inline');
           $("decline").css("background-color", 'efefef');
       }
});
```

Comment: typo mistake... you are not using `#` in your selectors like `$("auth")`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your Jquery statements. you forgot to mention `id(#)` or `class(.)` selectors.